# Retrieving size of shapefile in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, file-size

Is it possible to retrieve the size of a shapefile using python and arcpy?  If so, how?

Comment: Do you mean the amount of features? The area covered? The physical file size?

Comment: [os.path.getsize(path)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize)

Comment: yes, the physical file size. Sorry.  Thank you @gene

Comment: @gene Another silly question.  os.path.getsize() returns a integer.  is the default in KB's?

Comment: Return the size, in bytes, of path.

Comment: @gene is there a way to convert that to kilobytes?

Comment: You know that a shapefile is at minimum 4 files right? So if you really want to know its size on disk you should be totaling up all the files which make a shapefile.

Comment: [hurry.filesize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hurry.filesize)

Comment: 1kB = 1024 bytes, divide bytes by 1024 to obtain kilobytes (or was that kibibytes, just to confuse things). Likewise there's 1024kB in a MB (MiB), 1024 MB in 1 GB (GiB). Note that the size of the shape isn't *all* of the shapefile there's DBF, SHX at least and bound to be much more - you should add up all those files to obtain the *true* size on disc.

Comment: The size on disk is actually likely to be *larger* than the the sum of the bytes of the files, since disk-blocking at the OS level will likely require more than the bytes in the file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Iterate through all files in the shapefile directory with a [valid shapefile extension](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//005600000003000000) and add their sizes together. The `os` module is helpful for this task. Here's a function that returns the size of all shapefile files associated with an input shapefile in bytes. Use the full path of the shapefile as your input.

```
import os

def ShpSize (inShp):
    #standardize lowercase
    inShp = inShp.lower ()
    #shapefile extensions
    extensions = [".shp",
                  ".shx",
                  ".dbf",
                  ".sbn",
                  ".sbx",
                  ".fbn",
                  ".fbx",
                  ".ain",
                  ".aih",
                  ".atx",
                  ".ixs",
                  ".mxs",
                  ".prj",
                  ".xml",
                  ".cpg"]

    #shape file name without directory
    shpName = os.path.basename (inShp)
    #shape file name without .shp extension
    shpFlName = os.path.splitext(shpName)[0]

    #size set to zero
    size = 0
    #directory of shapefile
    shpDir = os.path.dirname (inShp)
    #iterate directory files
    for fl in os.listdir (shpDir):
        #standardize lowercase
        fl = fl.lower ()
        #skip file names that don't match shapefile
        flName = os.path.splitext(fl)[0]
        if not flName == shpFlName:
            #special case: .shp.xml file
            if not fl == shpFlName + ".shp.xml":
                continue
        #skip file names without proper extension
        ext = os.path.splitext(fl)[1]
        if not ext in extensions:
            continue
        #get size
        flFullPath = os.path.join (shpDir, fl)
        size += os.path.getsize (flFullPath)

    return size
```

Comment: Instead of listing all the files in `shpDir`, you can use `glob.glob(shpFlName + "*")` to only return files that have the same basename. Then it's just a filter on valid extensions.

Comment: That's true @Paul, glob is really handy however Emils' solution is native python and absolutely correct. The glob method should only be a side note as, in certain situations, users can't just install 3rd party software.. I would only support an answer that requires a 3rd party installation if there was no viable (or realistic) way of doing it in native python.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson `glob` is native, yea?

Comment: I don't think it is, I've got it and use it frequently but I'm semi-sure I had to download it.. I put it on my list of required plugins for a new installation before pyWin32. It may be that later versions come bundled, as with numpy, that would also make sense. I can't access a raw install to see if glob is there, having put it on the list to be installed it's always there; perhaps someone with a fresh/raw install of python could attest to that.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson - glob is in the standard python library - https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html and has been for a [very very long time](https://docs.python.org/release/1.5/lib/node89.html#SECTION007600000000000000000)

Comment: Thanks for sorting that out @Luke, I really wasn't 100% sure. So I can consider glob to be native henceforth and take it off my list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generator expression to efficiently find the shapefile size (i.e. including all associated files). The following method uses built-in Python 2.7 functionality.

```
import os, glob

ws = r'C:\path\to\your\shapefiles'  # input workspace

shapefiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(ws, "*.shp")) # List all .shp files

for shapefile in shapefiles:
    s = sum([os.stat(x).st_size for x in glob.glob(shapefile.split(".")[0] + "*")])
    print "The file size for %s is %s bytes or %s kb" % (shapefile, s, (float(s)/1000))
```

The generator expression does the following:

1. List all of the associated files of a shapefile. In this case, strip
   off the ".shp" extension from the path and use `glob` with the path
   and wildcard `*` to list all of the associated files
2. Get the file sizes in bytes using `os.stat`
3. Sum them using the generator `sum([...])`.